# How can I call a ros2 executable with arguments from a non-ROS file

Tags: python, ros2, parameters, smach, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two questions:
I would like to create a ROS API to start ROS nodes from a non-ROS python script.
For example the non-ROS python script: pick.py, would call the pick_ros.py to start a node (assuming that ROS is already running).
Even though this is not elegant, the only way I found to do that, is by writing in the Python script the terminal command:
os.system("ros2 run package pick")
My first question, is there another way to run ros2 run within Python?

Second, the pick method of the pick_ros executable ideally should take three arguments: x, y, z.
Is there a way to call the ros node with arguments, without declaring these as ros parameters? (the reason is, that the pick_ros.py calls smach (state machine), which is not a node. And declaring parameters can be done only in nodes)
So I would like something like: ros2 run package pick x=0.2, y=0.2, z=0.2

Edit: Declaring parameters however raises a type error:

I get x, y, z values from an action message (as floats - double type is not valid), whether ROS parameter types only accepts double type (no float) which for a reason identifies it as a type error.

In particular, my action msg is:

```
# Request
float64 x
float64 y
float64 z
```

and the pick node is:

```
def pick_sm(x=0.2, y=0.3, z=0.2):
    rclpy.init(args=None)

    node = rclpy.create_node('pick')
    
    node.declare_parameter('x')
    node.declare_parameter('y')
    node.declare_parameter('z')

    x_par = Parameter('x', Parameter.Type.DOUBLE, x)
    y_par = Parameter('y', Parameter.Type.DOUBLE, y)
    z_par = Parameter('z', Parameter.Type.DOUBLE, z)
```

When I call the pick_sm node through a non-ROS python script, I get this error:

```
AssertionError: The 'x' field must be of type 'float'
```

which prevents me from using these x, y, z fields as ROS parameters

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404301/how-can-i-call-a-ros2-executable-with-arguments-from-a-non-ros-file/) by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2022-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I put here how you could do that via python package ros2run.

```
from ros2run.api import get_executable_path, run_executable

executable_path = get_executable_path(executable_name="my_executable", package_name="my_package")
my_arg_values = ["myarg1", "myarg2", "myarg3"]

run_executable(path=executable_path,argv= my_arg_values)
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2022-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2022-07-28**:
That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Pablo!
But then I would like to know what is the best way to use these arguments in the ros node executable.

It could be somethine like:

```
import sys
    x = float(sys.argv[1])
    y = float(sys.argv[2])
    z = float(sys.argv[3])
```

or maybe it has to do with:

```
rclpy.init(args=None)
```

?

In ROS1 it would be:

```
rospy.myargv(argv=sys.argv)
```

what about the ROS2 equivalent?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-28**:
I would use ROS CLI: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Node-arguments.html to setup the node parameters. You have a nice tutorial with YAML parameters file there: https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-yaml-params/

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2022-07-28**:
thank you @ljaniec for your answer, however I wouldn't like to use yaml parameters since these are dynamically changing.

I could however use them as ROS parameters but oddly, I encountered some errors since x, y, z get their values from an action message (as floats - double type is not valid), whether ROS parameter types only accepts double type (no float) which for a reason identifies it as a type error.

And for that reason I was checking the possibility for sys.argv

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-28**:
Ok, dynamically changing parameters aren't currently possible AFAIK from documentation. This error with float/double seems a bit weird to be honest, maybe it is worth a try to debug? Could you add these error messages in the edit of the question?

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2022-07-28**:
I just edited the question to add these errors. Thank you for your help @ljaniec